# DatePicker open Programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I can't open a DatePicker nor a TimePicker Popup programmatically in Xamarin.Forms.

I tried the .Focus method alone, nothing happens.
I tried the bit more complex workaround of checking the Focus, unfocussing it and focus it again.
Then i tried all possible conditions with the IsVisible and IsEnabled Properties.

I just can't make it work.

Here's my CodeSnippet so far:

```
    private void BtnShareDay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BtnShareDay gedrückt");

        DatePicker dpday = new DatePicker
        {
            Format = "D",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            IsVisible = false,
            IsEnabled = false
        };

        dpday.Focus();
    }
```

EDIT:
If i add a Datepicker control to the XAML, i can't handle it as a button?

The related XAML:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                <BoxView HeightRequest="70"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnShareDay"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnShareWeek"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnShareMonth"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="70"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnSharePeriod"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnShareAll"/>
    
                <DatePicker x:Name="dpday"/>
    
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

EDIT2:
When adding the `IsVisible=false` property to the DatePicker in the XAML it does exactly what i want!

THANKS GUYS!!

Comment: you are dynamically creating a DatePicker but it isn't attached to your page, so calling Focus on it won't do anything.  You need to add it to your page's content, or just create it in your XAML instead of doing it dynamically.

Comment: But as i define it, i should be able to call it as a popup or not?

Comment: no, the picker control needs to be in the page layout in order for the popup to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it to the form before you open it.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: add it to your page layout